# How can i combine certain json data thats been defined into sets of strings instead?

Tags: python, json, api, discord.py

So basically im trying to make a json api fetch certain data and form it to make proxy credentials

`print('{proxyaddress}:{http}:{usernames}:{passwords}'.format(**vars()))`

this is my current code ^^^

id like it to print multiple that are like this

```
{proxyaddress}:{http}:{usernames}:{passwords}
{proxyaddress}:{http}:{usernames}:{passwords}
{proxyaddress}:{http}:{usernames}:{passwords}
{proxyaddress}:{http}:{usernames}:{passwords}
{proxyaddress}:{http}:{usernames}:{passwords}
{proxyaddress}:{http}:{usernames}:{passwords}
```

instead its like this

```
{proxyaddress}{proxyaddress}{proxyaddress}{proxyaddress}{proxyaddress}:{http}{http}{http}{http}
{http}:{usernames}{usernames}{usernames}{usernames}{usernames}:{passwords}{passwords}{passwords}
{passwords}{passwords}
```

I dont know how to fix this and ive been searching google a lot trying to figure it out, i appreciate any help.

edit:

its fetching json data so theres more than 1 username and more than 1 port, and proxyaddress ect:

```
ports = []   
  
for d4 in results:
    time4 = d4['ports']
    ports.append(time4)

    
    
    
proxyaddress = []
  
for d3 in results:
    time3 = d3['proxy_address']
    proxyaddress.append(time3)    
    
    
http = []   
    
for d5 in ports:
   time5 = d5['http']
   http.append(time5)
  
  
usernames = []

for d in results:
    time = d['username']
    usernames.append(time)
    
    
passwords = []
  
for d2 in results:
    time2 = d2['password']
    passwords.append(time2)
    
    
    
    
    

http = []   
    
for d5 in ports:
   time5 = d5['http']
   http.append(time5)
```

me defining the locations of the json ^

Comment: What is your code that print the multiples for now ? share it

Comment: How is `vars()` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zip up the individual lists:

```
for proxy, port, username, password in zip(proxyaddress, http, usernames, passwords):
    print(f"{proxy}:{port}:{username}:{password}")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop

```py
for i in range(6):
    print('{proxyaddress}:{http}:{usernames}:{passwords}')
```

And if you don't know how to handle json, import json package